# How can I properly authenticate a user as an admin in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am attempting to introduce "ghosting" into my application - wherein I can access our app from the POV of a user.

Currently using the `loginUsingID` function to achieve this, with a protected route only accessible by admins. However, I would also like to display to the admin that they are ghosting a user by displaying a bar across the top of our app.

I was thinking of adding a property to the user `is_being_ghosted` - setting it as false on `logout`, false on `login`, and true on `ghostLogin`.

But I realize there is a small chance an admin attempts to ghost a user, and it sets that property, and while they are investigating things within the account, the user themselves refreshes their page (they were already authenticated so do not need to login again). In that case they would see this "admin bar" across the top, which clearly I wouldn't want to happen.

Is there an efficient way to achieve what I'm trying to do here? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Set `is_being_ghosted` in session, not on the user. Session will only apply to the admin.

Answer (score 0):

As `jszobody` has mentioned. You could rather manage the state inside the session. You secure the `/ghost` route and then if the `original-user-id` session is set you display your bar and an `unghost` link.

```php
public function ghost(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->session()->put('original-user-id', Auth::user()->id);

    Auth::loginUsingId($id);

    return redirect('/');
}

public function unghost(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->session()->has('original-user-id')) {
        Auth::loginUsingId($request->session()->pull('original-user-id'));
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

**Update:**

The `ghost` endpoint basically accepts the `id` that you want to impersonate, typically found through an ajax search input or something similar. Whatever suites your use case.